# django-filter | first filter "------"

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filter

[image]

I want to rename first filter (all), now its like "--------", question is: how to let it name

filters.py:

```
class DoctorsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    category = ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=DoctorCategory.objects.all().order_by('category'),
            widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onchange":"submit();"}),
                     label='')

    class Meta:
        model = Doctors
        fields = ['category']
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/settings.html) you can set

```
FILTERS_EMPTY_CHOICE_LABEL = "(all)"
```

in settings.py